# Orientation change issue in iOS7 iPad with enquire.js

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7, media-queries, enquire.js

This is only occurring on iPad iOS7. Works perfectly on iOS6

When I open the page on Portrait, `topProducts.produtSliderEnable();` and `topProducts.tabletThreeItems();` functions had been called.

But

When I open the page on Landscape, then I change to Portrait, nothing is called. Only when I do a click event on a element that belongs to a function I showed below, then both is called

```
enquire.register("(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)", {
    match : function() {
        topProducts.produtSliderEnable();
        topProducts.tabletThreeItems();
    },
    unmatch : function() {
        topProducts.productSliderDisable();
    }
});
```

I have no clue why this is happening. Many thanks for any response.

==========================================

Functions if you want to look further, snipped out from my Literal Object

```
    produtSliderEnable: function () {
        if ($('.product-block .product-item').length === 4) {

            nextToggle.show();

            prevToggle.on('click', function () {
                $(this).hide();
                nextToggle.show();

                container.animate({
                    left: "0"
                });

                productItem.removeClass('active');
                productDetails.removeClass('active');
            });

            nextToggle.on('click', function () {
                $(this).hide();
                prevToggle.show();

                container.animate({
                    left: "-203px"
                });

                productItem.removeClass('active');
                productDetails.removeClass('active');
            });

            topProducts.swipeToggle();
        }
    },
    productSliderDisable: function() {
        if ($('.product-block .product-item').length === 4) {

            nextToggle.hide().unbind();
            prevToggle.hide().unbind();

            container.css({
                'left' : '0'
            });
        }
        $('.product-block').attr('id', '');
    },
    tabletThreeItems: function() {
        if (productItem.length === 3) {
            $('.product-block').attr('id', 'threeItems');
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://twitter.com/Falkowski/status/387294544988889089 |||||
https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/issues/79 |||||
https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/issues/83 |||||
https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/issues/66